# Why do we use the Option enum?

Tags: enums, rust

I don't get what the `Option` enum is for. I read that Rust doesn't have null values. The `Option` enum is defined like this:

```
enum Option<T> {
    Some(T),
    None,
}
```

I read its implementation and I came across this example:

```
fn main() {
    fn divide(numerator: f64, denominator: f64) -> Option<f64> {
        if denominator == 0.0 {
            None
        } else {
            Some(numerator / denominator)
        }
    }

    // The return value of the function is an option
    let result = divide(2.0, 3.0);

    // Pattern match to retrieve the value
    match result {
        // The division was valid
        Some(x) => println!("Result: {}", x),
        // The division was invalid
        None => println!("Cannot divide by 0"),
    }
}
```

When they could also do it like this:

```
fn main() {
    fn divide(numerator: f64, denominator: f64) -> String {
        if denominator == 0.0 {
            format!("Can't divide")
        } else {
            let x = numerator / denominator;
            format!("{}", x)
        }
    }

    let result = divide(2.0, 3.0);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Both programs output:

```
0.6666666666666666
```

Comment: I certainly wouldn't want to format my number as a string, just so I can parse it and convert it back to a number. That would be extremely inefficient, and ugly code. The original code is a fine example of the use of Option.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the above example is not a very good example of `Option`, but the following example shows `Option` at its very best:

```
fn main() {
    let name = String::from("naufil");
    println!(
        "Character at index 6: {}",
        match name.chars().nth(6) {
            Some(c) => c.to_string(),
            None => "No character at index 6!".to_string(),
        }
    )
}
```

When we are not sure whether there is a character at 6th element and you don't want your program to crash, `Option` comes to the rescue. Here is another example from [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html#matching-with-optiont):

> ```rust
> fn plus_one(x: Option<i32>) -> Option<i32> {
>     match x {
>         None => None,
>         Some(i) => Some(i + 1),
>     }
> }
>
> let five = Some(5);
> let six = plus_one(five);
> let none = plus_one(None);
> ```
>
> Listing 6-5: A function that uses a `match` expression on
>   an `Option<i32>`
>
> Let’s examine the first execution of `plus_one` in more detail. When we call
>   `plus_one(five)`, the variable `x` in the body of `plus_one` will have the
>   value `Some(5)`. We then compare that against each match arm.
>
> ```
> None => None,
> ```
>
> The `Some(5)` value doesn’t match the pattern `None`, so we continue to the
>   next arm.
>
> ```
> Some(i) => Some(i + 1),
> ```
>
> Does `Some(5)` match `Some(i)`? Why yes it does! We have the same variant. The
>   `i` binds to the value contained in `Some`, so `i` takes the value `5`. The
>   code in the match arm is then executed, so we add 1 to the value of `i` and
>   create a new `Some` value with our total `6` inside.
>
> Now let’s consider the second call of `plus_one` in Listing 6-5, where `x` is
>   `None`. We enter the `match` and compare to the first arm.
>
> ```
> None => None,
> ```
>
> It matches! There’s no value to add to, so the program stops and returns the
>   `None` value on the right side of `=>`. Because the first arm matched, no other
>   arms are compared.
>
> Combining `match` and enums is useful in many situations. You’ll see this
>   pattern a lot in Rust code: `match` against an enum, bind a variable to the
>   data inside, and then execute code based on it. It’s a bit tricky at first, but
>   once you get used to it, you’ll wish you had it in all languages. It’s
>   consistently a user favorite.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `Option enum` is used for the same reason the `Result` enum is used. It allows the programmer to see the breadth of returning values they might receive, but without having to dig through code you don't remember all the details about, or have never seen.

`Option` isn't a special value, it's just an enum, like `Result`. You could also use something like:

```
enum Division_Result {
    Successful(f64),
    DividedByZero,
}

fn divide(numerator: f64, denominator: f64) -> Division_Result {
    if denominator == 0.0 {
        Division_Result::DividedByZero
    } else {
        Division_Result::Successful(numerator / denominator)
    }
}
```

It just so happens that Optional values are some of the most common types of values that you have to deal with in a program. They're baked the Optional enum into standard because otherwise you would have to deal with everyone coming up with their own `enum` for the simple concept of an Optional value.

Returning an `enum` is an improvement over returning unwrapped magic values because it is more explicit to the programmer that the return value might diverge from what they wanted from the function.